# Time calculation pandas

Tags: pandas, rows

I need to calculate the time difference and then assign the results starting from the first row.
This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

dtime = pd.DataFrame({'letter': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], 'time': ['19/11/2019  06:02:39', '19/11/2019  06:32:39', '2019-11-19 06:42:39' , '19/11/2019  06:52:39', '19/11/2019  07:02:39', '19/11/2019  07:12:39']})
dtime['time'] = pd.to_datetime(dtime['time'])

dtime['Time_diff']=(dtime['time']-dtime['time'].shift()).fillna(0)
print (dtime)
dtime.to_excel('test_time.xlsx', 'Sheet1', index=True)
```

this is the output :

```
  letter                time Time_diff
0      a 2019-11-19 06:02:39  00:00:00
1      b 2019-11-19 06:32:39  00:30:00
2      c 2019-11-19 06:42:39  00:10:00
3      d 2019-11-19 06:52:39  00:10:00
4      e 2019-11-19 07:02:39  00:10:00
5      f 2019-11-19 07:12:39  00:10:00
```

but I need it to be this way:

```
  letter                time Time_diff
0      a 2019-11-19 06:02:39  00:30:00
1      b 2019-11-19 06:32:39  00:10:00
2      c 2019-11-19 06:42:39  00:10:00
3      d 2019-11-19 06:52:39  00:10:00
4      e 2019-11-19 07:02:39  00:10:00
5      f 2019-11-19 07:12:39  00:00:00
```

**row 0:     0      a 2019-11-19 06:02:39  00:30:00**

It is possible??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change order and add `-1` to [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html), also for replace missing values use `0 timedelta`:

```
dtime['Time_diff']=(dtime['time'].shift(-1)-time['time']).fillna(pd.Timedelta(0))
print (dtime)
  letter                time Time_diff
0      a 2019-11-19 06:02:39  00:30:00
1      b 2019-11-19 06:32:39  00:10:00
2      c 2019-11-19 06:42:39  00:10:00
3      d 2019-11-19 06:52:39  00:10:00
4      e 2019-11-19 07:02:39  00:10:00
5      f 2019-11-19 07:12:39  00:00:00
```